# section of n number of items from a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select three li on each click function. I need to hide all lis except first three. And on a click function I need to hide the first three li and need to show the next 3 items. How it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of both the jquery [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) and the [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selectors on your list in order to display the list items:

**Markup:**

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>    
    <li>12</li>
</ul>
<a class="prev">prev</a> | <a class="next">next</a>​
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('ul li:gt(2)').hide();

$('.prev').click(function() {
    var first = $('ul').children('li:visible:first');
    first.prevAll(':lt(3)').show();
    first.prev().nextAll().hide()
});

$('.next').click(function() {
    var last = $('ul').children('li:visible:last');
    last.nextAll(':lt(3)').show();
    last.next().prevAll().hide();
});
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/kRUUE/

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `:lt()` selector

Check out this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BzS9n/1/)